# How to debug Error 500 when calling google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).updateUi(e)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a working Google Apps Script Web App. All of a sudden the Web App stopped working and the browser console showed the following error:

`POST https://script.google.com/a/.../macros/s/.../callback?nocache_id=5&token=AJuLMu3sec_mObYWWeuh6qDTnZOGEbZUiQ%3A1706290571305 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I narrowed the problem down to the following call in the client code: `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).updateUiData(request)`

So the call of the server function updateUiData(request) seems to be suddenly causing the problem.

The code of the function onFailure is quite simple:

```
function onFailure(error){
   var errorString = JSON.stringify(error); 
   console.log("onFailureUpdateUi: "+errorString); 
  }
```

My Questions is:

- How can I find the root cause of the problem ?
- How can I debug the server side function calls triggered with google.script.run ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This was actually not a problem in my code, but a problem in the GAS infrastructure.
The following workaround worked for me:
Create a copy of the script file. Create a new deployment.
I was asked to grant all required auth scopes.
=> no more error 500